# Inner join in SQL/teradata does not return anything

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to select rows in a table where the names are the same, using INNER JOIN.

```sql
CREATE VOLATILE MULTISET TABLE TESTTABLE AS ( 
  SELECT a.COLUMN1, b.COLUMN2 
  FROM FIRSTTABLE AS a 
  INNER JOIN SECONDTABLE AS b ON a.NAMEIN1 = b.NAMEIN2 
) WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX(COLUMN1) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
```

But it returns nothing.. Can it be a problem of data type or did i code something wrong ?

Comment: Add sample data and maybe someone will be able to explain your current result.

Comment: When you run just the `SELECT` by itself, without the `CREATE TABLE` do you get any rows?  If you don't, then that means there are no matching rows in `FIRSTTABLE` and `SECONDTABLE` based on your join condition.  In that case, you'd need to make sure the data types are the same for both joining columns and they actually do have matching rows.  If you do get data, what is the exact `SQL` you are using to run your `SELECT` after you've created the table?  i.e. `SELECT * FROM TESTTABLE...`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, when I only run the SELECT i don't get any row either. When I look into the database manually there are some matches between a.NAMEIN1 and b.NAMEIN2, and both columns show a 'character' type when i hover over their names. Could it be the length of the character string that differs ?

Comment: Yes, it could be blanks or invisible control characters.

Comment: I thought that the '=' operator did not take the blanks at the right of the string into account ?

Comment: Are the columns `char` or `varchar`? And you are correct, Teradata will ignore trailing spaces for =.

Comment: Try changing your join condition to `INNER JOIN SECONDTABLE AS b ON TRIM(a.NAMEIN1) = TRIM(b.NAMEIN2)` and see if that returns any rows.  If it does, then it's a padding issue, in which case you should clean up / normalize your data :)